# Multiprocessing confusion - basics

Tags: python

Given extensive searching, I'm still having quite the trouble to get a specific function to run using multiple processes. The requirements are:

- limit number of proceses
- pass multiple arguments to map

The latest attempt runs, however time.sleep seems to be affecting all processes - execution time the same - 20sec, regardless if pool is used to multiprocess `foo` or `foo` called directly (it should be 4/20 seconds respectively). What am I missing?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Lock
import os
import time

def foo(arg):
    print '{} - {}'.format(arg[0], os.getpid())
    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_start_time = time.time()

    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    for i in range(20):
        arg = [i, i]
        pool.map(foo, [arg])

    pool.close() #necessary to prevent zombies
    pool.join() #wait for all processes to finish

    print 'Execution time {}s '.format(time.time() - script_start_time)
```

Results:

```
0 - 5660
1 - 5672
2 - 5684
3 - 5704
4 - 5716
5 - 5660
6 - 5672
7 - 5684
8 - 5704
9 - 5716
10 - 5660
11 - 5672
12 - 5684
13 - 5704
14 - 5716
15 - 5660
16 - 5672
17 - 5684
18 - 5704
19 - 5716
Execution time 20.4240000248s
```

Comment: change `map` to `map_async`.

Comment: Pool.map blocks until all the passed iterable is evaluated. Call map once with all the arguments and you'll get concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments, `pool.map` will block until execution is complete, so you must either submit jobs with `apply_async` or `map_async` and use a callback to handle your function returning data. Alternatively you could build all your inputs ahead of time, and call `map` on all of them at once.

In this example apply_async and map_async are quite similar, with the difference being that apply_async can only submit one job at a time, and supports passing multiple args and kwargs. Example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time

def add(a, b):
    c = a+b
    print(f'{a}+{b} = {c} from process: {os.getpid()}') #python 3 f-strings are nifty :)
    time.sleep(1)
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_start_time = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    results = []
    for a in range(5):
        for b in range(5,10):
            pool.apply_async(add, (a,b), callback=lambda c: results.append(c))
    pool.close() #necessary to prevent zombies
    pool.join() #wait for all processes to finish
    print('results', results)
    print('Execution time {}s '.format(time.time() - script_start_time))
```

Take note of how the arguments are passed when calling `apply_async`.

Alternately you could pass the arguments all at once using a normal map, however this requires that your function take only a single argument. This is where the `starmap` method is useful. It takes an iterable of tuples, and unpacks the tuples into the function arguments, so an input of `pool.starmap(foo, [(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)]`) will unpack each pair into foo, which takes two arguments:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    script_start_time = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    args = [(a,b) for a in "abc" for b in "ABC"]
    print(pool.starmap(add, args)) #same add function from before (works with strings too)
    pool.close() #necessary to prevent zombies
    pool.join() #wait for all processes to finish
    print('Execution time {}s '.format(time.time() - script_start_time))
```