# List of job list with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I need to run 100 query in parallel, but I don't have enough resources, so I have created a list with 20 sublists, each sublist contains 5 processes.

Now I want to run the job lists successively. 
I explain more : when the first five queries are finished, the second five will be launched, etc...

I did this :

```
jobs_list = []
for sublist in list_all:
    jobs = []
    for cd in sublist:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_zio, args=(cd,))
        jobs.append(process)
    jobs_list.append(jobs)

for l in jobs_list:
    for j in l:
        j.start()

for l in jobs_list:
    for j in l:
        j.join()
```

But I was running at 100% of CPU

Where I was wrong ?

Thank you !

Comment: If I count right, you are running **100** `process`. Read about: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to join the sublist before starting the next.

```
jobs_list = []
for sublist in list_all:
    jobs = []
    for cd in sublist:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=calc_zio, args=(cd,))
        jobs.append(process)
    jobs_list.append(jobs)

for l in jobs_list:
    for j in l:
        j.start()
    for j in l:
        j.join()
```

Comment: Thank you, now i understand
It seems to work. I'am running between 40% and 65% of CPU and I have only 5 python.exe launched

Comment: @AdamAdam as stovfl mentioned in the comments, this would likely be a good place to use `multiprocessing.pool` that way you can keep a given number of processes running at all times. With this implementation, if one of the 5 or so takes a lot longer than the rest, much of the time for that batch will be taken to run a single process. A pool will therefore both give you the ability to limit resources consumed, as well as keep the load more consistent.

Comment: this is what I am trying to do now, but I can't find a useful example with multiprocessing.pool

Comment: @AdamAdam I just wrote another answer using `pool.apply_async`, and `pool.starmap`. It should be a good place to start.

Comment: I can not see your new answer @Aaron

Comment: @AdamAdam does [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188005/multiprocessing-confusion-basics/44188348#44188348) link work?